# LPTSTR + CFile Write issue

Tags: c++, cfile, lptstr

I am trying to read items from CListBox and writing to a file using CFile.

Here is my code

```C
int count = m_lstSelectedItems.GetCount();

CFile cfile_object;
cfile_object.Open( L"C:\\temp.txt",  CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeReadWrite);

for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
{       
    int n;
    LPTSTR s2 = new TCHAR[256];
    memset(s2, 0, 256);

    n = m_lstSelectedItems.GetTextLen(i);       
    m_lstSelectedItems.GetText(i, s2);

    cfile_object.Write (s2, n);     
    cfile_object.Write("\n",2);

    delete[] s2;
}

cfile_object.Close();
```

But I am getting this data

```
 F:\Programs\Test\SelectDialo੧䘀㨀尀倀爀漀最爀愀洀猀尀吀攀猀琀尀匀攀氀攀挀琀䐀椀愀氀漀最开
```

Any suggestions to get correct data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Able to solve it using CT2CA function

```
int n;
CString str;

n = m_lstSelectedItems.GetTextLen(i);
m_lstSelectedItems.GetText(i,str);

CT2CA outputString(str, CP_UTF8);
cfile_object.Write(outputString, ::strlen(outputString));
cfile_object.Write("\n",1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx